# OpenApi 3 on single object as parameter controller

Tags: spring-boot, openapi

We have an openapi definition as follow:

```
  filterParameter:
  name: addCartEntriesByFilterParameter
  in: query
  schema:
    type: object
    required:
      - "applicationCode"
    properties:
      applicationCode:
        type: string
      [...others]
```

that is used in

```
/api/v1/applications/{applicationCode}/filtered:
put:
  tags:
  - Tag
  operationId: byFilter
  summary: Add filters
  parameters:
    - $ref: '#/components/parameters/applicationCode'
    - $ref: '#/components/parameters/filterParameter'
  responses:
    "400":
      $ref: '#/components/responses/400BadRequest'
    "404":
      $ref: '#/components/responses/404NotFound'
    "200":
      $ref: '#/components/responses/Response'
```

We would like to use only one single DTO as parameter, but we must declare two because one is a "path" param and others are "query" params. Is there a way of include all that params, "path" and "queries", in one single object when is received by Spring Boot controller?

Desired definition could be something like this, without duplicated "applicationCode" param in path and query:

```
/api/v1/applications/{applicationCode}/filtered:
put:
  tags:
  - Tag
  operationId: byFilter
  summary: Add filters
  parameters:
    - $ref: '#/components/parameters/filterParameter'
  responses:
    "400":
      $ref: '#/components/responses/400BadRequest'
    "404":
      $ref: '#/components/responses/404NotFound'
    "200":
      $ref: '#/components/responses/Response'
```

Thanks in advance